# picture post on facebook give error

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using javascript API for posting a Picture to facebook

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos",
    data : {
        message : "Good One",
        url : photoUrl,// URL of Image to post on facebook ,e.g https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2642324404/46d743534606515238a9a12cfb4b264a.jpeg
        access_token : getCookie("fbTocken"),//this is the access tocken which i got frome facebook ,saved it in cookies which I am fetching
        format : "json"
        },
        success : function(data) {
        alert("POST SUCCESSFUL");
        }
      )}
```

Everything works fine, the problem is that when I change

```
photourl
```

to localhost image url  like `http://localhost:8980/xcloud/resources/images/logo.png`

facebook returns error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

other normal urls I am able to post to facebook and works fine

(project is in java with tomcat as server)

Comment: when you save access tokan in cookie , make sure you really secure with XSS ,if a hacker steal cookie , he can post user facebook .

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Facebook server can't access your localhost URL. You should sit on real IP and provide an address which is accessible by Facebook. 
Ajax call you use just pass the URL for photo, which further is downloaded by Facebook system.